# Passing NSMutableArray with modal view

Tags: xcode, nsmutablearray

I have 2 views, in the second one I initialize a `NSMutableArray` and I want to pass it back  to the first View. In the second view I have a button connected with the following action:

```
-(IBAction)back:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]
}
```

With this action I go back from my second ViewController to the first ViewController, is there a way to pass the NSMutableArray from that action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using `prepareForSegue` then you can user `NSUserDefaults`:

```
-(IBAction)back:(id)sender {
    NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:mutableArray forKey:@"array"];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    //I'm guessing you are going to load the viewController that's up next?
}
```

You can retrieve it in the viewDidLoad like so:

```
// to retrieve in maybe viewDidLoad?
    NSArray * array = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]arrayForKey:@"array"];
    NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [array mutableCopy];
```